Tikz graph with log-axis position shape
I am trying to position something on a log-axis graph with no success. I have given up on drawing the shape properly with the right coordinates but now I can't position the shape when I have drawn it.
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                hobby}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        ban/.style={fill=orange!80, draw=none},
    ]
        \begin{loglogaxis}[
            xlabel={Temperature (K)},
            ylabel={$L/L_\odot$},
            xmin=2000, xmax=40000,
            ymin=1e-4, ymax=1e6,
            xtick={2000, 3000, 5000, 10000, 30000, 40000},
            xticklabels={2000, 3000, 5000, 10000, 30000, 40000},
            ytick={1e-4, 1e-2, 1, 1e2, 1e4, 1e6},
            x dir=reverse, % Reverse the x-axis for Temperature
            grid=both,
            minor tick num=5,
            major grid style={black!50},
            minor grid style={gray!25},
            xticklabel style={anchor=north east, rotate=45}, % Slant the labels
            enlargelimits={0.05}, % //Adds 10% extra space
            ]


      % This was the only way I could get the shape anywhere near.  
  \scoped[on background layer]{
                \shade[use Hobby shortcut, closed=true, inner color=orange!80, rotate=-30]
                (20000, -10) % First point at (20,000 K, 1,000 L/L⊙)
                .. (3000, -20)  % Point at (3,000 K, 100,000 L/L⊙)
                .. (3000, -30)  % Point at (3,000 K, 1,000,000 L/L⊙)
                .. (10000, -10)  % Point at (10,000 K, 1,000 L/L⊙)
                .. (20000, -10); % Close back to the first point
            }

 \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Hertzsprung-Russell Diagram with Supergiants Region (Banana Shape)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

the shape is right but the coordinates are obviously wrong.

I tried;
\node[anchor=south west] at (axis cs:20000, 1e3) {
  \scoped[on background layer]{
                \path[use Hobby shortcut, closed=true, inner color=orange!80, rotate=-30]
                (2000, -10) % First point at (20,000 K, 1,000 L/L⊙)
                .. (300, -20)  % Point at (3,000 K, 100,000 L/L⊙)
                .. (300, -30)  % Point at (3,000 K, 1,000,000 L/L⊙)
                .. (1000, -10)  % Point at (10,000 K, 1,000 L/L⊙)
                .. (2000, -10); % Close back to the first point
            }
      };

to just position it after it was drawn but that didn't work either. Ideally I would draw the shape with the right coordinates but being able to position it would do. Any help?
